# MYSQL query to get dates from all years around today

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with data points for every day of the year with a few year's history. Now I want the average of the data for the dates around today, 15 days in the past and 15 days in the future.
Normally this would work with something like

```
select average(data_point)
from my_table
where dayofyear(point_date) between dayofyear(now()) - 15 and dayofyear(now()) + 15
```

If the current day is 01-11-2021, then this gives an average over all days from october 16 to november 16 for all years.

But this does not work when the current date is within 15 days of the new year. If the current date is 21-12-2021 then `dayofyear(now()) + 15` for is `370` and you only get dates from december 6th until december 31st. It should return decembr 6th until january 5th.

It will also not work when you modulo on 365 because then the dayofyear would result in `between 340 and 5` and that returns no results.

Any hints how to accomplish this?

Comment: @ysth Why would that matter?

Comment: You can check whether the current date is within 15 days of the start or end of the year, and use `OR` to include the dates from the end or beginning of the year. The only complication is that the excess at the beginning of the next year depends on whether it's currently a leap year or not.

Comment: @BerndBuffen that's subtly different, since dayofyear is effectively doing date(now()), not now()

Comment: @ysth - UUUPS - My Mistake - Sorry, i remove my message

Comment: @Barmar I was misreading the question, never mind

Comment: "If the current day is 01-11-2021, then this gives an average over all days from october 16 to november 16 for all years." this is incorrect: for leap years, it will be october 15 to november 15.  I'm guessing this is not intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really confused that the previous solutions don't work.
However, I found a solution that I also tested. all you have to do is adjust the number of days and the fields you want to see.
I'm considering whether to add a ticket to MariaDB.

this query works:

```
SELECT m2.* FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(point_date)
  , STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR(point_date),'0101'),"%Y%c%D" ) + INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(NOW())-14 DAY AS from_date
  , STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR(point_date),'0101'),"%Y%c%D" ) + INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(NOW())+14 DAY AS to_date
  FROM my_table
) AS m1
INNER JOIN my_table AS m2 ON m2.`point_date` 
BETWEEN m1.`from_date` AND m1.`to_date`;
```

**sample**

I have create a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `cp` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `point_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

and fill it with data (100 rows)

** test with all fields**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM (
    ->   SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(point_date)
    ->   , STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR(point_date),'0101'),"%Y%c%D" ) + INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(NOW())-14 DAY AS from_date
    ->   , STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR(point_date),'0101'),"%Y%c%D" ) + INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(NOW())+14 DAY AS to_date
    ->   FROM my_table
    -> ) AS m1
    -> INNER JOIN my_table AS m2 ON m2.`point_date` 
    -> BETWEEN m1.`from_date` AND m1.`to_date`;
+------------------+------------+------------+-----+------------+
| YEAR(point_date) | from_date  | to_date    | id  | point_date |
+------------------+------------+------------+-----+------------+
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  56 | 2022-01-06 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  57 | 2022-01-05 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  58 | 2022-01-04 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  59 | 2022-01-03 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  60 | 2022-01-02 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  61 | 2022-01-01 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  62 | 2021-12-31 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  63 | 2021-12-30 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  64 | 2021-12-29 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  65 | 2021-12-28 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  66 | 2021-12-27 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  67 | 2021-12-26 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  68 | 2021-12-25 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  69 | 2021-12-24 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  70 | 2021-12-23 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  71 | 2021-12-22 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  72 | 2021-12-21 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  73 | 2021-12-20 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  74 | 2021-12-19 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  75 | 2021-12-18 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  76 | 2021-12-17 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  77 | 2021-12-16 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  78 | 2021-12-15 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  79 | 2021-12-14 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  80 | 2021-12-13 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  81 | 2021-12-12 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  82 | 2021-12-11 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  83 | 2021-12-10 |
|             2021 | 2021-12-09 | 2022-01-06 |  84 | 2021-12-09 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 422 | 2021-01-05 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 423 | 2021-01-04 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 424 | 2021-01-03 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 425 | 2021-01-02 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 426 | 2021-01-01 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 427 | 2020-12-31 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 428 | 2020-12-30 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 429 | 2020-12-29 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 430 | 2020-12-28 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 431 | 2020-12-27 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 432 | 2020-12-26 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 433 | 2020-12-25 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 434 | 2020-12-24 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 435 | 2020-12-23 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 436 | 2020-12-22 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 437 | 2020-12-21 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 438 | 2020-12-20 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 439 | 2020-12-19 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 440 | 2020-12-18 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 441 | 2020-12-17 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 442 | 2020-12-16 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 443 | 2020-12-15 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 444 | 2020-12-14 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 445 | 2020-12-13 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 446 | 2020-12-12 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 447 | 2020-12-11 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 448 | 2020-12-10 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 449 | 2020-12-09 |
|             2020 | 2020-12-08 | 2021-01-05 | 450 | 2020-12-08 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 787 | 2020-01-06 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 788 | 2020-01-05 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 789 | 2020-01-04 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 790 | 2020-01-03 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 791 | 2020-01-02 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 792 | 2020-01-01 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 793 | 2019-12-31 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 794 | 2019-12-30 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 795 | 2019-12-29 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 796 | 2019-12-28 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 797 | 2019-12-27 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 798 | 2019-12-26 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 799 | 2019-12-25 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 800 | 2019-12-24 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 801 | 2019-12-23 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 802 | 2019-12-22 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 803 | 2019-12-21 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 804 | 2019-12-20 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 805 | 2019-12-19 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 806 | 2019-12-18 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 807 | 2019-12-17 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 808 | 2019-12-16 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 809 | 2019-12-15 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 810 | 2019-12-14 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 811 | 2019-12-13 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 812 | 2019-12-12 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 813 | 2019-12-11 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 814 | 2019-12-10 |
|             2019 | 2019-12-09 | 2020-01-06 | 815 | 2019-12-09 |
+------------------+------------+------------+-----+------------+
87 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: No, that also does not go past the new year. When I run this now, it only selects dates from december 7 (or december 6 in leap years) until december 31.

Comment: @Maarten Deen - i have change my answer. please test it

Comment: Yes that works. And it is new for me that you can apparently use a table of results in a between like that. Of even use between like that without a where clause.

Comment: ups, sorry, i also dont know it with the WHERE clause. its a copy paste error from me :-). So the BETWEEN is not FROM the SELECT it is from THE JOIN

Comment: But it still works! *confused* Will start omitting 'where' from my queries in the future.